# Java Lambda: bug or feature with Predicate

Tags: java, lambda, java-stream

I attempted to make a multiple line `Predicate` by first adding curly brackets but Eclipse complains about the following code:

```
Stream<String> stringStream = temp.flatMap(x -> Arrays.stream(x));
Stream<String> stream = stringStream.filter(x -> {"a".equals(x.toString());});
```

It says after placing a red line under filter: "The method `filter(Predicate<? super String>)` in the type `Stream<String>` is not applicable for the arguments `((<no type> x) -> {})`"

Is this because multiline predicates are not allowed or am I making some other mistake?

Comment: Aside: `stringStream.filter("a"::equals)` would be sufficiently equal for the code in question.

Answer (score 2):

If you use brackets, you need to include the `return` keyword. If it is a  single expression you can omit both the brackets and the return keyword.

Answer (score 0):

The `{}` make a small block of code.  So you need to return true or false int the predicate.

```
Stream<String> stream = stringStream.filter(x -> {return "a".equals(x.toString());});
```

Answer (score 0):

Either do this,

```
Stream<String> stream = stringStream.filter(x -> "a".equals(x.toString()));
```

or add the `return`

```
Stream<String> stream = stringStream.filter(x -> {return "a".equals(x.toString());});
```